# Multithreading C not being faster

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, opencv

I am writing a program to convert (using opencv) images to a desired size, all given by command line arguments. I am using pthreads to multi-thread but in my tests the single-threaded program had a very close performance to the multi-threaded program.

It is actually my second code design, first I was reading all images first and assigning them to the threads after. It was too memory-consuming and I changed that.

Would I have to use fork() or something more process-related to make it run on a efficient parallel way? Would appreciate your suggestions!

Since the code is too long to fit here, I put it on paste.ubuntu.com.

The main program takes and pass the argv arguments correctly to the convert function.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10314628/

Comment: We're not going to follow links in order to sift through huge wads of code.  Reduce your code to its essence (i.e. a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and then post it here.

Comment: Are your threads by any chance sharing one bottleneck resource? Many programs are I/O bound, and your harddisk doesn't become faster just because your program is multi-threaded.

Comment: it is not that big, but I can shrink it a bit... I put it that way because it is kind of the program as whole that should work better :).

Comment: It looks like you're doing the convert on threads, but opening the images and allocating all the memory on the initial thread.  Are you sure the conversion is the expensive part?  Have you profiled any of this?

Comment: that is a very good point, I will try changing this. because as I said when opening all files first the program took more time doing it than actually converting. I will do some changes and give feedback, thanks!

Comment: Isn't opencv using the gpu? Aren't gpu queries serialised?

Comment: OT, not being ultimately familiar with OpenCV, I take great risk in mentioning this, but `thread_original_images[i] = cvLoadImage(file_address, 0)` is outside your first-call logic, and I see nothing that suggests that allocation is ever freed, including in the thread proc, so unless I'm reading this wrong you have a helluva memory leak.

Comment: in general, multiple threads is not expected to be faster, overall, than a single thread.  This is due to the extra processing involved in switching between threads.  The thread paradigm works best when large delays are expected in the thread processing, such as when a connection is made between a client and server.  then each server connection should be passed to a thread.  And the thread waits for responses from the client.

Comment: I will only try the new things tomorrow, but yeah a friend of mine told me that I should do a complexity analysis in order to know if multi-threading is a good alternative for the problem. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @user3629249 ... or if you have a multi-processor system, like most modern systems.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the deprecated C OpenCV API anymore

Comment: did you measure cpu-time or wall-time? (HOW did you measure the time?)?

Comment: I didn't want to use C but it is a extra point exercise from my university, and the professor said I should use only C ;).

Comment: @GPPK I got the execution time from codeblocks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions, I guess I fixed all the problems and now it is more than 2x faster using multithreading! After @jeffamaphone asked if the conversion was the expensive part I tried moving the load image inside the threads and the program instantaneously got a lot faster. I am managing the memory with cvReleaseImage() and it is working perfect as well.

Here is the new code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10345572/

Thanks a lot for the help!